# Unsupported feature error

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

I am trying to compile this piece of code in VHDL, using Altera 10.2, but I get this error:

> Unsupported feature error: non-locally-static attribute names are not supported

I asked my instructor some help on this error message, but he said that my source code looked fine to him and it was supposed to compile correctly.

```
if ((ina'event AND ilvla=ilvlb) AND (ilvla=NOT ilvlc)) then
    if (ilvla=lvla AND ilvlb=lvlb AND ilvlc=lvlc) then
        ilvla <= '0';
        ilvlb <= '0';
        ilvlc <= '0';
        clk   <= '1';
    else
        ilvla <= (ilvlc AND ilvlb AND NOT ilvla) OR (ilvla AND NOT ilvlc) OR (ilvla AND NOT ilvlb);
        ilvlb <= ilvlb XOR ilvlc;
        ilvlc <= NOT ilvlc;
    end if;
else
    rst <= '1';
end if;
```

The error occurs on the first line with the `if` statement.

Comment: compile for simulation, or for synthesis? That first line will most definitely not synthesise!

Comment: i do not know ... i am about to do the simulation but there is only one compile option in altera's menu ...

Answer (score 1):

What are your intentions with 'event?  Are you trying to create a flip-flop?  If not, you should not be using 'event.  If so, you missed on the basics of finding a rising edge.  They are one of the following three:

```
if Clk = '1' and Clk'event then
if Clk'event and Clk = '1' then 
if rising_edge(Clk) then  -- *** Preferred for readability.
```

There really is no form that allows you to check for 'event of some signal and whether you are matching and/or not matching some other signal.

In addition, the structure you are using is inappropriate for a flip-flop.  You are assigning a value within an else branch of the clock which is going to make tools unhappy.  In addition synthesis tools are happiest if clock is only in the outer most if branches.  The following two are common for flip-flops:

```
SimpleFF : process(Clk) 
begin
  if rising_edge(Clk) then
    -- other stuff
  end if ; 
end process SimpleFF ; 

  AsyncResetFF : process(Clk, nReset) 
  begin
    if nReset = '0' then 
      -- reset stuff
    elsif rising_edge(Clk) then
      -- other stuff
    end if ; 
  end process SimpleFF ;
```

While you are writing code, you are creating hardware.  Never forget this.  Step one is to always draw a rough picture of what you want.  In particular, identifying hardware elements, such as flip-flops, combinational logic, and arithmetic logic.  Then write code that captures what is in the picture.

Comment: I did the change you said, but now there is a new error that occurs: '[%DLS-F-NullArg, Null owner node argument to FindAttibute.]' but here there is no line highlighted.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Divide and conquer!  Meaning setup a project just to compile the offending file.  Remove half of the code.  Did the error go away?  If no, the error is not in this portion of the code - pursue the other half of the code.  If yes, divide the code in half again and repeat.  Early EDA tools were not as good as today's, but the debug techniques come back from time to time.